# Out of Gas, Bad Jump, Other errors trying to send

Tags: error

I have always used the metamask default settings, however it is not working when I am simply trying to send ether from my etherdelta smart contract back to my ether wallet, so I checked www.ethgasstation.info and manually set above the safe range. but nothing I do seems to work, my transaction either sits for 24 hours and gets cancelled, or my gas is used up within minutes and it says error out of gas.

Currently while waiting for over 2 hours for transaction approval I saw the warning "error there was an error upon resubmitting" so I clicked the link to increase my gas, only to immediately receive the same message "warning there was an error upon resubmitting" and my transaction again has been awaiting approval for over another hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the message "Out of Gas" your exchange was successfully completed. However, there was an error sending the ETH/ETH token to you because the specified address was an ETH contract address as the withdrawal address. The contract address you provided requires more gas than we typically use to send ETH which is why this failed with an error of “out of gas”.You need to contact contract owner with an ETH address that does not have contract restrictions.